# Is `2d_array` here a pointer to another array of integers who has `width` number of elements?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

The code:

```
int (*2d_array)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(int));
```

Below is the distribution code from an online class, where RGBTRIPLE is a struct. Someone said *image is a pointer to an array of length width of RGBTRIPLE*. And so `2d_array` here is also a pointer to another array of integers who has `width` number of elements?

```
RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
```

I am just really confused about this syntax. How does the parenthesis change the meaning of image? How should I interpret `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width]`? From left to right?
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Please show us actual code, copy-and-pasted from something that compiled successfully. `2d_array` is not a valid identifier. Please read this: [mre]

Comment: You read variable declarations *starting at the variable name*, going right when you can, left when you must, and respecting parentheses. Just read it out: "`image` is pointer to array of `width` `RGBTRIPLE`s". If you got rid of the parentheses it'd be "`image` is array of `width` pointers to `RGBTRIPLE`".

Comment: You have two declaration you need to be able to distinguish (using `int` for example), `int *arr[n]` and `int (*arr)[n]`. The first is *an array of pointers* (`n` of `int*` pointers). The second is *a pointer to array* of `int[n]` -- that is a pointer to an array. Your declaration for `image` is *a pointer to array* of `RGBTRIPLE[width]`. Your allocation `calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE))` allocates storage for `height` number of those arrays, effectively allocating what you reference as `image[x][y]` where `x < height` and `y < width`.

Comment: See ["The Clockwise/Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can interpret `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width]` as `RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width]`. Where `RGBTRIPLE` is probably a `typedef`ed `struct`.

For e.g.

```
typedef struct {
  // data members
}RGBTRIPLE;
```

So, in `RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width]`, `image` is a **pointer to array** of user-defined data type `RGBTRIPLE`, similar to `int (*ptr)[width]` which is a **pointer to array** of `int` type.

Note: In C, you can only declare a variable name which starts with a underscore or a letter. This `int (*2d_array)[width]` is wrong as far as I know.

---

I assume `2d_array` is `_2dArray`.

> And so `_2dArray` here is also a pointer to another array of integers who has `width` number of elements?

**Yes**

> How does the parenthesis change the meaning of the image? How should I interpret `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width]`?

These are called *Complex Pointers*. E.g. `pointer to array == int (*ptr)[LEN];` or `pointer to function == int (*ptr)(//function arguments);`

If you don't put parenthesis around `image` i.e. `RGBTRIPLE *image[width]` it will be `array of pointers`. So you must put parenthesis around `image` if you want it to be a `pointer to array`.

Just interpret it as `image is a pointer to an array of width elements of type RGBTRIPLE`.

Comment: You have the undercore rule a bit off, see [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/3422102). The parenthesis effect [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) which is the reason for the difference.

Comment: Well, I don't know about `C++`. But in `C`, you can do `_Name/_name/__name/__Name`.

Comment: The same applies in C++ so long as the name is not declared in global namespace. So that part is right, it just didn't convey the rest of the story. For example `_X` would not be correct.

Comment: As I already mentioned I don't know much about C++. But to test `_X`, I declared `int _X = 2;` in a program in C using GCC and it worked.

Comment: Variable name **may** start with underscores in C, that is true. Simply an implementation is allowed to declare a number of global symbals for internal use. The rule is that those internal symbols must start with an underscore. As that list is unspecified, when you use a variable with a name starting with an underscore, it may collide with one of those internal symbols. What is even worse IMHO is that it can work fine with a compiler an break with a different one (implementation dependance)...

Comment: ... That is the reason why *best practices* recomment to not use user level symbols starting with an underscore.

Comment: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use." For example `<stdio.h>` could declare `_X` as a typedef... so your program could work for as long as you didn't include `<stdio.h>`...

Comment: **David C. Rankin, Serge Ballesta and Antti Haapala** I understood your point and in future I'll try not to declare a variable starting with an underscore as far as possible. Thanks for this new information that _underscored variables are generally used as internal symbols_. I really didn't know about this.

Answer (score 0):

> And so `2d_array` here is also a pointer to another array of integers who has `width` number of elements?

Yes.

Note that identifiers aren't allowed to begin with a number. So, `2d_array` is an invalid identifier.

> Below is the distribution code from an online class, where `RGBTRIPLE` is a struct.

To be nitpicky, a pure structure needs to be classified by the `struct` keyword. This isn't the case here, but I guess `RGBTRIPLE` is high-probably a `typedef` alias for a pure structure.

Just that as side note.

> I am just really confused about this syntax. How does the parenthesis change the meaning of image?

`RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width]` - `image` is a pointer to an array of `width` elements of type `RGBTRIPLE`.

`RGBTRIPLE *image[width]` - `image` is an array of `width` pointer to `RGBTRIPLE`.

It's a big difference. Either you got only one pointer to an array of `width` `RGBTRIPLE` or you got an array of pointers to `RGBTRIPLE`.

The parenthesis changes the whole context.

> How should I interpret `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width]`? From left to right?

Think in the [Clockwise Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) and read it clockwise from the identifier (middle).

This has been subject of:

- [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262/12139179)